# How can I found out if it is possible to cancel a certain async task with CancellationTokenSource?

Tags: c#

I want to find out if it would be possible to cancel the task with CancellationTokenSource. How can I found out if it is possible to cancel a certain async task?

```
public async Task PlayerAccountDetails()
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    try
    {
        await UpdatePlayerCountryData("Germany", "Berlin");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var excep = ex.Message;
    }
}

private static async Task UpdatePlayerCountryData(string country, string city)
{
    var resultprofile = await PlayFabClientAPI.UpdateUserDataAsync(new PlayFab.ClientModels.UpdateUserDataRequest()
    {
        Data = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
               {"Country", country},
               {"City", city}},
               Permission = PlayFab.ClientModels.UserDataPermission.Public
    });

    if (resultprofile.Error != null)
        Console.WriteLine(resultprofile.Error.GenerateErrorReport());
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Successfully updated user data");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't cancel tasks - you cancel methods. The method has to accept a `CancellationToken`, and has to periodically check whether it's been cancelled. If you're asking whether you can cancel your `UpdateUserDataAsync` method, then check whether there's an overload which accepts a `CancellationToken`

Comment: Cancellation is **cooperative**. If the code you're calling doesn't know about the cancellation token, there's zero chance it's going to be able to observe the cancellation and terminate its activities early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a practical example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = Task.Run(async () => await WatchYourCarBurn(cancellationTokenSource.Token));

        Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(5000)).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Too much time elapsed, cancel task.");
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

        while (!task.IsCompleted && !task.IsCanceled)
        {

        }
    }

    private static async Task WatchYourCarBurn(CancellationToken token)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You notice some fog");

        await Task.Delay(2000);

        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        Console.WriteLine("You notice some fire");

        await Task.Delay(2000);

        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        Console.WriteLine("You notice your car");

        await Task.Delay(2000);

        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        Console.WriteLine("You notice your car is burning");

        await Task.Delay(2000);

        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        Console.WriteLine("You watch your car burning");

        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` and `Task.Run(..., cancellationToken)`. That way `task` will show up as `Canceled`.

Comment: Will await Task.Delay(5000)).Wait() block the thread? I don't want to block it.

Comment: @canton7 What exactly should I change? I don't know what you mean with: cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() and Task.Run(..., cancellationToken)

Comment: Instead of doing `if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return`, do `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`. That throws a recognisable exception if a cancellation occurs. Instead of doing `Task.Run(async () => await WatchYourCarBurn(cancellationTokenSource.Token))`, do `Task.Run(async () => await WatchYourCarBurn(cancellationTokenSource.Token), cancellationTokenSource.Token)`. That tells `Task.Run` to recognise exceptions that come from that `CancellationToken` you gave it, and to mark the `Task` it returns as `Cancelled` instead of `Faulted`

Comment: @canton7 edited my answer, effectively IsCanceled is never true without using token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

Comment: It looks like your call to `Task.Run` still doesn't pass the `CancellationToken`?

Comment: @canton7 I tought it was necessary too, but I actually tested it and it correctly works that way. I guess it catches the throw from the method's token.

Comment: Weird, maybe they changed that recently. It wasn't the case last time I checked it

Answer (score 0):

> How can I found out if it is possible to cancel a certain async task?

In the general case, you can't.

One [common pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#cancellation-optional) is that cancelable asynchronous methods take a `CancellationToken` as a parameter, e.g., check for this overload:

```
await UpdatePlayerCountryData("Germany", "Berlin", cts.Token);
```

However, sometimes that parameter is ignored, so it's not a *guarantee* that the cancellation request will be honored.